# Problem to display to execute a function when clicking on a button inside a leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet

I'm struggling with a simple issue in JS. I have a Leaflet map with a bunch of markers, when clicking on a marker you have a popup with some info and two buttons. I try to display a div with more info when the button is clicked. It seems that when i click on it, the div is displayed and all the other one as well. The condition seems true for all the marker in the loop which is not correct as only one button is clicked.

Do you guys have any idea ?

```js
$.getJSON(uri, function(data){
      for (let river in data.rivers){

          var popup = data.rivers[river].name +
              '<br/><b>Water Level :</b> ' + data.rivers[river]['water-level'] + " m3/s" +
              '<br/><b>Water Temperature :</b> ' + data.rivers[river]['temperature'] + " °C" +
              '<br/><b>Sample Time :</b> ' + data.rivers[river]['date-and-time'] +
              '<button type="button" id="more-infos" class="btn btn-primary">More infos</button>' + " " +
              '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Alert me</button>';

          // The problem is here
          $("div").on('click', '#more-infos', function (e) {
            onClickMoreDetails(data.rivers[river]);
          });

          var marker = new L.marker(L.latLng(parseFloat(data.rivers[river].latitude), parseFloat(data.rivers[river].longitude)));
          marker.bindPopup(popup);
      }
  });
  
  
  function onClickMoreDetails(data){
    console.log(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I didn't use any ids in template that might be duplicated.

Second – to determine which river's info you want to show I used data attribute `data-river="'+i+'"` on more info button.

And after all in mouse click handler get data attribute value from `event.target` and retrieve your data from an objects map.

```js
function onClickMoreDetails(event){
  console.log(data.rivers[event.target.dataset['river']]);
}
```

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/fqL9g6cb/